# NSTimer start delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an `UIButton` that triggers a `NSTimer` with 1 sec interval, it calls a selector  a countdown, this countdown is shown in the screen. We have detected that the `NSTimer` does not start immediately, it costs one second aprox. to begin. Is there anyway to force `NSTimer` to start immediately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSTimer` has a `fire` method. call it after initialization.

check the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/fire